# Saml2ClaimTypes is hardcoded for NameId,NameIdFormat,SessionIndex

Tags: itfoxtec-identity-saml2

I tried to send logout request to IDP using Saml2LogoutRequest . It is reading the claim value from the principal which we are passing as params . But in the code , they are reading the claim values based on the hardcoded values of itfoxtec  whereas we have our own claim name type and name id type. How to resolve this ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5KzqM.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVJSj.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Saml2LogoutRequest constructor without the ClaimsPrincipal parameter. After creation the Saml2LogoutRequest object can be populated with NamenID, NameIDFormat and SessionIndex.

```
var saml2LogoutRequest = new Saml2LogoutRequest(config);
saml2LogoutRequest.NameId = new Saml2NameIdentifier("..NameID..", new Uri("..NameIDFormat.."));            
saml2LogoutRequest.SessionIndex = "..SessionIndex..";
```